# SQL SERVER 2008 , Nested procedures issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Considering the following example

```
Procedure1
..........
IF(@errorcode<>0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
ELSE COMMIT TRANSACTION
SELECT @errorcode

Procedure2
..........
WHILE [condition] BEGIN
   EXEC @proc1result = Procedure1 [parameters]
   IF(@proc1result=0) SET @totalresult=@totalresult+1
END
SELECT @totalresult
```

The problem is that @totalresult is incremented correctly but the value returned by Procedure2 is 0.
How to get it right?

I am using sql server 2008 and Entity Framework 4.
Procedure1 works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) For the first stored procedure, you should use `RETURN @errorcode` and not `SELECT @errorcode`. This is also *my* recommendation.

**OR (NOT AND)**

(2) For the second stored procedure, you should use `INSERT ... EXEC Procedure1` like this:

```
WHILE [condition] 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Results TABLE (RetValue INT PRIMARY KEY);

   INSERT @Results
   EXEC Procedure1 [parameters];

   --IF 0=ALL(SELECT a.RetValue FROM @Results a)
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Results a WHERE a.RetValue <> 0)
      SET @totalresult=@totalresult+1;

END
SELECT @totalresult
```

Comment: If the transaction from procedure1 rollback i get "Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement." exception, If everything goes well and Procedure1 commits every time i get the right result.

Comment: @gigi: If you look at my answer you will see my recommendation. For a stored procedure, `RETURN @something` must be used to return the error code while `SELECT something ...` must be used to return a record-set.

Answer (score 0):

"but the value returned by Procedure2 is 0"

You do a `SELECT @totalresult`. Should it be `return @totalresult`?

Answer to Upendra...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TestReturn (@InValue int)
AS
Return @Invalue+1
GO

declare @value int
exec @value = TestReturn 100
select @value
```

Comment: How can return statement will return in procedure ?. It should work in function.

Comment: Since i am using Entity Framework , it seems that i need to use select instead of return to return a scalar value